What should be marked global in a packaged InvocableMethod action class?
I'm writing some InvocableMethod Annotation code that will be packaged and in the documentation what is marked global varies somewhat from example to example.
What I observe is:

The top-level class must be global.
The @InvocableMethod can be left public.
Inner classes used for the request and response must be global but am fairly sure these can be left public.
The @InvocableVariable properties of those inner classes can be left public.

Is this correct?

What we have found:

The invocable method class and method (we assumed this latter) must be global if you are allowing the subscriber to use this in their own flows (i.e. not just in packaged flows, but in subscriber flows including overrides and template instances).
The parameter and result nested classes must be global since they are used in the signature of the global method.
If you want to allow the customer to call the logic from only the flow context, the parameter and result nested class attributes can be public but if you want to allow them to directly call this from their own Apex, these must be global.

It sounds, from your findings, that our assumption that the method itself must be global is inaccurate, and this may have a knock-on for our understanding in point 2, above.
Since we are already making the invocable method class and method global we have decided to make the attributes for input parameters and results also global to allow Apex invocation of the logic.
